# Creating views programmatically

Tags: android

I'm a new android developer and I decided to create a simple test app that has 6 editViews and calculates the average of those numbers inputted.

I am looking to find out how to create the views programmatically when needed instead of wasting resources on having all of the views there OnCreate.

I've been searching around but have been unable find out how to implement it. If someone could help out that would be great.

Thanks!

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    average = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.average);
    edit_message = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            s1  = edit_message.getText().toString();
            s2  = editText.getText().toString();
            s3  = editText2.getText().toString();
            s4  = editText3.getText().toString();
            s5  = editText4.getText().toString();
            s6  = editText5.getText().toString();
            if(!s1.isEmpty()) {
                n1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                counter++;
            }
            if(!s2.isEmpty()) {
                n2 = Integer.parseInt(s2);
                counter++;
            }
            if(!s3.isEmpty()) {
                n3 = Integer.parseInt(s3);
                counter++;
            }
            if(!s4.isEmpty()) {
                n4 = Integer.parseInt(s4);
                counter++;
            }
            if(!s5.isEmpty()) {
                n5 = Integer.parseInt(s5);
                counter++;
            }
            if(!s6.isEmpty()) {
                n6 = Integer.parseInt(s6);
                counter++;
            }
            if(counter>0) {
                s1 = String.valueOf((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 + n6) / counter);
                average.setText(s1);
            }
            else {
                average.setText("0");
            }

            counter = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: show the community what you've implemented

Comment: Oops sorry about that. It's my first post on this forum. So basically I just have 6 EditViews there but if for example my user only wanted the average of 3 numbers than I am wasting resources for those 3 extra views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details, I'll give you at least a place to start. You can instantiate `TextView`s programmatically and then add them to your layout.

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
parent.addView(tv);
```

`context` should be your `Activity` or `Fragment` that this text view will be apart of. The `parent` should be a `ViewGroup` in your XML layout that can have multiple children like a vertical `LinearLayout`. Hopefully this is enough information to guide you to better Google Searching.

**EDIT**

`LinearLayout` - Not a list layout, brain fart.

Comment: Yeah that should give me enough to go on. I'll try making a list layout and then add the EditViews to the list. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample just for reference:

The layout file:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="add" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/del"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="del" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sum" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the activity:
    package com.example.test;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout container;
    Button add;
    Button del;
    Button sum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.del);
        sum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sum);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                EditText edit = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                edit.setLayoutParams(params);
                edit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                container.addView(edit);
            }
        });

        del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count = container.getChildCount();
                if (count > 0)
                    container.removeViewAt(count - 1);
            }
        });

        sum.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int count = container.getChildCount();
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    EditText edit = (EditText) container.getChildAt(i);
                    String numStr = edit.getText().toString();
                    if (numStr == null || !(numStr.length() > 0)) {
                        sum += 0;
                    } else {
                        sum += Integer.parseInt(numStr);
                    }
                }

                Log.i("Test", "sum = " + sum + " avg = " + (sum * 1.0f / count));
            }
        });
    }
}
```